# how do i create a huge json file

Tags: json, perl

I want to create a large file containing a big list of records from a database.
This file is used by another process.

When using xml i don't have to load everything into memory and can just use [XML::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aWriter)

When using [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) we create normally a perl data structure and use the to_json function to dump the results.

This means that I have to load everything into the memory.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Is JSON suitable for large files?

Comment: I'm not a big perl user, but i suspect that you'll need to break your data structure into smaller bits and write them to the file in a loop to avoid the memory overhead - at least if i was doing this in PHP that's what I'd try.

Comment: How would you then parse this file? Which php library would you use to parse this created file?

Comment: I understand now. You could just write every json to a different row. In the parsing we could just read every line and parse it back.

Comment: That doesn't work if it's a single data structure. There are no lines in that case. How large are we talking about?

Comment: @simbabque why not? ;) hope you´r fine ? :)

Comment: Because it will be a single line if it's a single data structure. OP is talking about a *big list*. That implies he has an array. Thus, he cannot convert it line by line because each line is part of the array. @Alex show up some time again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [JSON::Streaming::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON%3a%3aStreaming%3a%3aWriter)

Description

```
Most JSON libraries work in terms of in-memory data structures. In Perl, JSON 
serializers often expect to be provided with a HASH or ARRAY ref containing 
all of the data you want to serialize.

This library allows you to generate syntactically-correct JSON without first 
assembling your complete data structure in memory. This allows large structures 
to be returned without requiring those structures to be memory-resident, and 
also allows parts of the output to be made available to a streaming-capable 
JSON parser while the rest of the output is being generated, which may 
improve performance of JSON-based network protocols.
```

Synopsis

```
my $jsonw = JSON::Streaming::Writer->for_stream($fh)
$jsonw->start_object();
$jsonw->add_simple_property("someName" => "someValue");
$jsonw->add_simple_property("someNumber" => 5);
$jsonw->start_property("someObject");
$jsonw->start_object();
$jsonw->add_simple_property("someOtherName" => "someOtherValue");
$jsonw->add_simple_property("someOtherNumber" => 6);
$jsonw->end_object();
$jsonw->end_property();
$jsonw->start_property("someArray");
$jsonw->start_array();
$jsonw->add_simple_item("anotherStringValue");
$jsonw->add_simple_item(10);
$jsonw->start_object();
# No items; this object is empty
$jsonw->end_object();
$jsonw->end_array();
```

Furthermore there is the [JSON::Streaming::Reader](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON%3a%3aStreaming%3a%3aReader) :)